# Which option enables object size tracking and __builtin_object_size?

Tags: gcc

When `__builtin_object_size(ptr, 1)` is used in code compiled without optimization (`-O0`), it always returns -1. In order to get actual object size, code must be compiled with at least `-O1`. I would like to enable it at `-O0` too, but so far I am unable to find which option enables it. I checked outputs printed generated by gcc executed with options `-Q --help=optimizers`, `-Q --help=common` and `-Q --help=c` and found which options are added by `-O1`. Unfortunately when I added them manually to command line, `__builtin_object_size` still returned -1.

Do you know if it is possible to somehow enable this feature when compiling at `-O0`?

I am using gcc 4.8.4 on Linux/x86_64.

For reference I am adding code which I used for testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

inline void f(const char* ptr)
{
    printf("%d\n", (int)__builtin_object_size(ptr, 1));
}

int main()
{
    char* buf = malloc(10);
    f(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, have you tried to pass the `-fsanitize=object-size` flag to the compiler?

Comment: Without -O2 you need to use type 0: `__builtin_object_size(ptr, 0)`, not 1. 
1 is only for _FORTIFY_SOURCE=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, gcc does not run analysis passes necessary to compute result of `__builtin_object_size` at `-O0`.